# Server validation with mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, rest, mongoose

Let's say you have this schema setup in mongoose:

```
var personSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  address:{
    city: String,
    postalCode: Number
  }
```

});

You have this post:

```
// /api/person

exports.newPerson = function(req, res){
var person = JSON.parse(person);
//Validation code here
mognoose.model('person').create(person

res.send(200)
```

}

What's the best way to check that all keys are provided in the post? If anything is missing, I would like to have a 400 error with a message like: 'insufficient data provided, check docs..' or something like that.

You could do:

```
if(!person.name || !person.address ..){

  res.send(404, {message: 'Not sufficient data'})
  return;
}
```

But is this the best way to do it? What if you have a schema with 30 keys? Is there any nicer way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
var personModel = new mongoose.model('person');
personModel.set(person); // just set temp person object
personModel.save(function (err, saved) {
    if (err) {
        // your 400 error
        return;
    }
    // saved = person with mongoDb fields seted (_id, __v, ...)
});
```